# Creation of loading screen for a particular div

Tags: ajax, loading

How can I create loading screen only for a particular `div` while loading the content through ajax? The loading screen should be confined within the `div` only.

Comment: Well, as you can probably imagine, this question is much too broad without describing in much more detail what environment your in.

Comment: Also, you should tag your question more appropriately.

Comment: I'm a dummy for this stackoverflow.com site sorry I didn't know that? but can you guys just tell me how to do it using simple native html,css and javascript..

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the content once the user invokes an action or event (e.g. via a 'Load' button) my suggestion would be to have the HTML to create the loading screen stored in a JavaScript variable in your JS source like:

```
var loadingHTML = '<p>Loading...</p>';
```

Set the contents of the `<div>` to `loadingHTML` on invocation of the event, then invoke the AJAX call which once complete you set the contents of the `<div>` once again to be an HTML response returned from the call.

Alternatively if you are loading the content via AJAX on page load then simply have the contents of the `<div>` set to be something like `<p>Loading...</p>` then immediately invoke the AJAX call on

```
$(document).on('ready', function () { 
      ... 
});
```

if you're using jQuery for example.

As above once the call completes set the contents of the `<div>` with JavaScript to the response data.